# iPhone 5 stuck on "your iPhone is being restored"

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

I got an iPhone 5 and restored it from the iCloud backup of my iPhone 4. Now when I look at the iCloud backup settings for the iPhone 5, it says "Backup options will be available when your iPhone is restored from this backup." It seems to think it is still restoring, but I believe it finished yesterday. I can click "Stop Restoring iPhone", but I'm afraid I will lose some data; is there any way to check what's going on?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check to make sure it is not downloading any apps still (check all folders and pages to see if any apps are still greyed out to show not yet downloaded) and not downloading any songs either (check under downloading in iTunes). If it isn't, try turning off your phone, then turn it back on. If that doesn't work, hold the power and home button until you see the Apple logo to do a restart.

Comment: Thanks for the iTunes idea! It turned out there were a couple songs that hadn't downloaded because they were associated with another Apple ID. Letting them finish fixed it.

Comment: Also check your Camera Roll -- the pictures can take quite  a while to download from the cloud.

Comment: Where is " downloading in iTunes " is this in the iphone itself?

Comment: @NickWebb No, that's in the iTunes application on your computer. Just make sure there are no downloads still running.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. No apps for songs. Hard reset didn't help. This is pathetic. Happens to me nearly every time.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - the best thing is to force a boot with no network connection.

1. enable AirPlane mode
2. power off normally, by holding sleep/wake and sliding the red control
3. power up - it will still be in AirPlane mode
4. inspect the last of the screens - and in the folders on the last page to make sure no icons are still "downloading"
5. connect to iTunes and see if it's still downloading
6. disable AirPlane mode and let it sit for 60 seconds to resume downloading anything (hopefully you are in a fast Wi-Fi for this - especially if some apps are larger than the normal size for a data connection download)

If after all this is done, you may be forced to stop restoring and potentially lose data that has changed since then and now, but it clearly is programmed to stop the restore and leave you with what you have.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have **the latest iOS version installed before you start the restore**. In my case the replacement unit I got had iOS 7.0.3 installed and the restore would get stuck at some point. I was able to install the 7.0.4 update *while* the restore was stuck using my Mac and iTunes. After updating the system, the iPhone restartet and continued with the restore. I hope it will complete the process eventually. It is still running at the moment...

See "[iCloud: Restore your iOS device from iCloud](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12521)":

> You must update your device to the latest version of iOS to make sure
>   you can restore from a recent backup of another device, such as a lost
>   or broken device.

Good luck to you!

Next time I will make sure to have a manual backup of my device on my Mac before a planned replacement. Shoud be significantly faster than iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

I had that exact problem and only thought every last thing had been downloaded.  However when I went to iTunes on my phone, some songs had not downloaded.  When I tapped them, it started the download and as soon as that was done, the message went away and my phone is now able to be backed up to the iCloud once more.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My iPhone 5s seemed unable to complete a backup to iCloud after/during an initial restore. The iCloud Backup button was grayed out and unresponsive to touch gestures in the "BACKUP" section under **Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup**.

I solved it by downloading the iOS 7.0.2 update. After installing the update and a restart of the phone, the Backup button showed on and active. Backup to iCloud started and appears to be going fine. Currently shows 4 minutes remaining (thought I'd go ahead and post this rather than wait until backup is complete).

Comment: If backup is really ongoing, then it won't let you install the update. That's the situation I'm running into. The update screen says "You can install this update when you iPhone is finished restoring from the iCloud backup."

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.

I realized that my iPhone 5 would not complete restoring because I had several songs on my phone that I had downloaded from someone else's computer. My phone asked me to put in the password for their Itunes email (I was confused why) and I hit cancel.

So... I went to iTunes and deleted the songs that were gray, I reset the phone (hold the home and lock buttons), and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your old phone is backing up to the cloud. I was having the same problem until I turned off backup on my old phone. Then the restore finished immediately